# RestKit › [RestKit 0.9] Swap core data database at runtime

Tags: restkit

Le mardi 18 juin 2013 12:50:29 UTC+2, Appsido a écrit :
Hello,

I'm facing an issue trying to create a new persistent store at runtime and use this new persistent store.

To create the new persistent store i use the following snippet

```
NSURL *modelUrl = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"AppDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelUrl];

[[AppDelegate appDelegate] objectManager].objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"AppStore"
                                                                                                      usingSeedDatabaseName:nil
                                                                                                         managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel
                                                                                                                   delegate:nil];
```

This works fine and create a new persistent store on the iphone device file system.

Then i create a new object and save it in the persistent store with the following snippet

```
MyEntity *f = [MyEntity object];
[f setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:70] forKey:@"id"];
[f setValue:@"New Family" forKey:@"name"];

NSError *error;
[[f managedObjectContext] save:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"error > %@", error);
```

The object is saved in persistent store but not the new created one but the old one.

So is it possible to define multiple persistent store based on the same data model file and swap from one to another at runtime, and keep data in each persistent store instance.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

```
// get the default context
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
// create the other context
NSManagedObjectContext *myNewContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
// set the new default
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:myNewContext];
```

You will need somewhere to strore the contexts to keep swapping between them, maybe a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks to pointing me to Magical Records but unfortunately i'm not using it. The application is based on RestKit which have a RKManagedObjectStore with ManagedObjectContext readonly. Before i have to change the application Core (RestKit to Magical Records) i'm looking for a RestKit solution

Comment: Ah i see your point maybe restkit will base its NSManagedObjectContext on the Magical Records newly created context. I'll give a try

Comment: I tried using Magical Records snippet but restkit seems not using the newly created context

Comment: How are you updating the content? are you using `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: Yes i'm using NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: I finally have found a work around using RestKit method deletePersistantStoreUsingSeedDatabaseName with a seedDatabase on the device generated at runtime

Comment: make sure you have a class which responds to `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and implement the methods to update your table once the new data has been added to the `fetchedResultsController`

Answer (score 0):

You should at first delete old one persistentStore with this code

```
[objectManager.objectStore deletePersistantStore];
```